# Making dropdown dependent lists using the UNIQUE() function in Excel

Tags: excel, list

I am making dependent lists using the UNIQUE() function and I'm running into a problem... Here is the context:

I have a worksheet called "Code" containing all the data (hence, all the categories and the corresponding products) and a worksheet called "Result" that contains the final dropdown list.

Here is what I have in the code worksheet

[image: Here is what I have in the code worksheet]

Here is what I have in the Result worksheet

[image: Here is what I have in the Result worksheet]

In the code worksheet, in cell A2, I wrote this function: `=SORT(UNIQUE(Result!H3:L3;TRUE;TRUE))`
The sort function is to have my result in alphab. order and unique since i may extend my list over the years, so I purposely left blank cells but I don't want them to appear in my dropdown list.

In the same sheet, in cell A5, I wrote this function: `=SORT(UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(Result!C4;Result!H3:L3;Result!H4:L8);;TRUE))`

Now going on the result sheet, in cell C4, I went to the data tab, data validation and I chose list and input this:
[image: List for categories]

And following the same logic, in cell D4, I have this:
[image: List for products]

Now for the column of category, I simply copied the list and input it in the rows bellow it until row C12 and I still get the 3 choices : gaming, productivity and school. However, I get a problem when it comes to the products column. When I copy the list from cell D4 and put it in cell D5, the list is still linked to the cell C4. However, I need it to be linked to cell C5. In that same logic, I need cell D6 to be linked to cell C6, D7 to C7, etc.

Any help is very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible without VBA. At least you would need the selection_change-event to recalculate. Then you can use `cell("row")` to retrieve the active row. If VBA is an option I can provide the solution.

Comment: I can't test it because i don't have Excel 365, but maybe instead of using `=SORT(UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(Result!C4;Result!H3:L3;Result!H4:L8);;TRUE))` you could use `=SORT(UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(0,-1,4,0,"Result"),FALSE);Result!H3:L3;Result!H4:L8);;TRUE))`?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your quick replies, @Ike I can use VBA so go ahead and try what you had in mind:)

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey When I write the formula, I get #CALC! I don't know why, apparently the formula is referenced to an empty cell? I think the mistake is in the ADDRESS() part since I checked everything else and it makes sense.

Comment: It's probably because it's used in cell A2. Maybe used in a name it could work. Anyway, a solution has already been proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is using `CELL("row")` which returns the row of the current selection. BUT only after a calculate - therefore we need the selection_change-event

```vb
=LET(d,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(configProductCodes,
    (configCategories=INDEX(userCategory,CELL("row")-1,1)) * (configCategories<>""),""),TRUE,TRUE)),
FILTER(d,d<>0))
```

I am using named ranges - as you can see in the screenshot.

The formula is placed in `E9` which is called `dropdownValues`.

You need this code in the worksheet:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Me.Range("dropdownValues").Calculate
End Sub
```

Any time you change the selection formula gets recalculated based on the current row.

Use this cell for your validation list.

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly thank you very much!! I'll try to put the "coding" and the big "table" with all the categories and products in another sheet and see if that still works. In the future, I want to hide the coding sheets and only keep the result sheet showing up. I'll update this comment later on:)

Comment: Update: Alright so there's a problem with this formula, everytime I select the product in the list so for example "chair", the dropdownValues cell writes #REF! and I have to go on that cell and hit on the Enter key (as if I re-wrote the formula from A to Z) for the list to re-show me all the options. The thing is, if I choose a category like gaming and I choose "xbox" and then let's say I change my mind and meant to click on "ps4" straight away, it won't work since i'd get the #REF! problem.

Comment: I also know there's the function OFFSET that could make everything work, the problem is, I get zero or blanks that appear in the list and I do NOT want them to show up, I just need to see the actual options.

Comment: if you moved the formula to the hidden sheet then you have to update `Me.Range("dropdownValues").Calculate` to use the hiddensheet

Comment: I finally decided to keep the formula in the same sheet as the Results but I just hid the column instead, did that to cause less problems :)